# Why is the redirect url is of longer length?

Tags: http, redirect, saml-2.0

I have been reading on SAML 2 binding mechanism. It says [below](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-6.4/how-to-setup-sso-with-saml-v2/) :

HTTP REDIRECT VS. POST BINDINGS: Both SPs and IDPs can transmit and receive messages using redirect or POST bindings. Due to the limitation of URL lengths in certain scenarios, HTTP Redirect is usually used when passing short messages, and HTTP POST is used when passing longer messages.

I am unable to understand how a response with the same length can be longer in redirect than it is in post. I think I am missing something very basic. Could anyone help to clear that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects utilize the querystring to pass data, which has a size limitation that is not present in a post.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

Example Get:

```
/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Example Post:

```
POST /test/demo_form.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

the parameters for a get are located within the URL itself, which has a size limitation of 2083 characters (there is some variation to this number).  For a post, the information to go along with the post is in the actual body of the message, rather than the URL.

Basically you get more "room" in a post, as you're not going to hit a size restriction on URL because your information is in the body - unless your URL is already that long which would mean it'd be an issue for gets or posts.

> Why is the redirect url is of longer length?

I think you might be misunderstanding, it's saying you get ***less*** room for a redirect than a post, not more/longer.  Gets have a size restrictions, posts do not, or at least it's a configurable setting on the server and has a larger "higher end" than a get request would.